# SQL Alchemy Composite Key Order

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create a composite primary key of the form (date,id). My code currently looks somewhat like this

```
class Gyroinfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'GYROINFO'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement = True)
    date = Column(DateTime, primary_key = True)
```

but this defaults to a primary key of the form (id, date). How can I switch the primary key order?

Comment: Does initializing date before id works. I cannot understand why the order makes the difference

Comment: Initializing date before id does not seem to work.

Comment: Can you give us the example of why the order is important? It is a constraint so order does not make any difference.

Comment: I want to put an index of the form (date,id) on the table, and so if I can set the primary key to be of the form (date,id) we will not have to declare any additional index.

Comment: What database are you using? I just did a quick test with `sqlite` and changing the definition order of the columns did change the order that the columns are specified in the emitted sql. E.g. id/date: `CREATE TABLE "GYROINFO" (id INTEGER NOT NULL, date DATETIME NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (id, date))` and date/id: `CREATE TABLE "GYROINFO" (date DATETIME NOT NULL, id INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (date, id))`.

Comment: I reproduced the issue on MySQL, so I assume that is the backend you are using. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've assumed you are using MySQL here, so if not let me know and I'll remove this answer.

You can read what Mike Bayer has said about reordering of Primary Key fields with MySQL [here](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3726/incorrect-primarykeyconstraint-with). And the rational behind why `SQLAlchemy` behaves like this, [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_11.html#no-more-generation-of-an-implicit-key-for-composite-primary-key-w-auto-increment).

You can achieve what you want through using a `PrimaryKeyConstraint` and a separate `UniqueConstraint` on the `id` field. E.g.:

```
class Gyroinfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'GYROINFO'

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    date = Column(DateTime)

    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint(date, id),
    )
```

Which produces the following sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `GYROINFO` (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        date DATETIME NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (date, id),
        UNIQUE (id)
)
```

Without the extra `unique=True` in the `id` field definition, SQLAlchemy emits a `CREATE TABLE` with the columns ordered as you wish:

```
CREATE TABLE `GYROINFO` (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        date DATETIME NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (date, id)
)
```

But it's rejected by `MySQL`:

```
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

However, it begs the question as to why you need your `date` field in the primary key at all. As `id` is auto-increment, it will be unique across all entries into the table, so including `date` in a composite field with `id` adds nothing for the extra complexity. I'd stick with:

```
class Gyroinfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'GYROINFO'

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime, index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! We're actually using PostgreSQL, which accepts the SQLAlchemy command. As to why we wanted date in the primary field- we're working with a time series extension (timescaledb) which requires the primary key of your tables to include dates.

Comment: Makes sense. Glad I could help.

Comment: This strategy does not work for `PostgreSQL`... There's no way to decide the order of the primary key index.